# Determining Author post count

Tags: wp-query

This is more of an efficiency question as the following code does do what I want.

```
$user_name = get_the_authour;
$query = new WP_Query('author_name=JustinH');
        $author_post_count = $query->post_count;

        if ($author_post_count >= jwh_option('post_count_set') {
            $post_status = 'publish';
        }else{
            $post_status = 'pending';
        }
```

That query pulls back all the user meta and all the data for their posts. Is there a more precise way to get to:

```
$query->post_count;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/count-posts-of-an-specific-author-in-authorphp) on the wordpress codex shows how you can scope your SQL query:

```
$author_post_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_author = '" . $$username->ID . "' AND post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'");
```